# How to find the JRE path on Windows using command line

Tags: java, windows, bash, command-line, command-prompt

`java -XshowSettings:properties -version | findstr "java.home"` doesn't work, because it prints multiple lines.

Comment: From the cmd line, `where java` shows where java.exe is found (otherwise `echo %java_home%` if it is set)

Comment: @Daniele , where java is getting the path of java, but that is different than the path `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oddly enough, described `java` output goes to `STDERR` text stream. Apply [`2>&1` redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) as follows:

```
2>&1 java -XshowSettings:properties -version | findstr "java\.home"
```

> ```
>     java.home = C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201
> ```

The same in ˙wsl˙ (Ubuntu) command prompt:

```
java.exe -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1 | grep "java\.home"
```

> ```
>     java.home = C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201
> ```

Comment: You can also use `java --version` to make java write the version to the standard output instead of the standard error stream.

Answer (score 1):

`JAVA_HOME` is not set by default in Windows Java. Instead, it lists itself in the registry. The value `CurrentVersion` in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment` indicates the version, and `JavaHome` under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\{version}` provides the path.

Comment: When you've got an JDK installed, but also a JRE elsewhere, this is the way to find the JRE path it will use.